# ffmpeg output the time(mm:ss) with scan the black screen in the vdeo file

Tags: ffmpeg

I use the below command to detect the black screen in the video, but it can't output the time field with detected. May I know does have any command can let ffmpeg output the time format with "mm:ss:sss" in the detected?

```
ffmpeg -i "inputfile.mkv" -vf "blackdetect=d=2:pix_th=0.00" -an -f null -
```

Output:

```
[blackdetect @ 0000024d543c41c0] black_start:876.009 black_end:878.011 black_duration:2.002
[blackdetect @ 0000024d543c41c0] black_start:893.026 black_end:895.028 black_duration:2.002
```